# Is it possible to get all messages history or get messages count from any chat in telegram

Tags: api, telegram

I need to calculate messages count in telegram or get messages history.
Tell me, is it possible to do this?
I know, that i can see messages count in chat from some member in telegram desktop. Maybe i can do this in any conversation?
Thank you!

Comment: each channel has its own auto increment postNo. you can find the number of messages in the channel by the postNo of the last message.
e.g. you can see the the 21st message of the "telegram news" channel by this link: http://www.t.me/telegram/21

Comment: @tashakori maybe you know how works this api method?
https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory

Comment: Yea, but its usage may defer a bit in difderent clients or APIs. The common thing to know in all of them is that you should have channel_id(unique for every channel) and access_hash(unique for every user-channel pair). And you may call this method by playing with its parameters like: max id, offset date, limit, ... . Checkout getHistory#afa92846 in this link for full signature: https://tjhorner.com/tl-schema/

Answer (score 1):

You can count messages in telegram, get messages history and do plenty of other things with Telegram API. Here is a brilliant article that describes the process step by step: https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-the-telegram-api-b0cd220dbed2

It worked like a charm for me both for retrieving messages and counting them. Let's look at the code from the article:

```
counts = {}
# create dictionary of ids to users and chats
users = {}
chats = {}
for u in dialogs.users:
    users[u.id] = u

for c in dialogs.chats:
    chats[c.id] = c

for d in dialogs.dialogs:
    peer = d.peer
    if isinstance(peer, PeerChannel):
        id = peer.channel_id
        channel = chats[id]
        access_hash = channel.access_hash
        name = channel.title

        input_peer = InputPeerChannel(id, access_hash)
    elif isinstance(peer, PeerChat):
        id = peer.chat_id
        group = chats[id]
        name = group.title

        input_peer = InputPeerChat(id)
    elif isinstance(peer, PeerUser):
        id = peer.user_id
        user = users[id]
        access_hash = user.access_hash
        name = user.first_name

        input_peer = InputPeerUser(id, access_hash)
    else:
        continue

    get_history = GetHistoryRequest(
        peer=input_peer,
        offset_id=0,
        offset_date=None,
        add_offset=0,
        limit=1,
        max_id=0,
        min_id=0,
    )

    history = client(get_history)
    if isinstance(history, Messages):
        count = len(history.messages)
    else:
        count = history.count

    counts[name] = count

    print(counts)
```

Let's add sorting:

```
sorted_counts = sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for name, count in sorted_counts:
    print('{}: {}'.format(name, count))
```

We got messages counter result:

```
Group chat 1: 10000
Group chat 2: 3003
Channel 1: 2000
Chat 1: 1500
Chat 2: 300
```

P.S. Here is a simple (user's) way to get some chats from official wiki, but from my perspective it's very limited and unsuitable for programmatic purposes:

https://telegram.wiki/general/exporting-chats

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19483080)

Comment: @E.Moffat fair enough. Updated accordingly.